# Android MediaPlayer OnCompletionListener not called in JUnit Testcase (AndroidTestCase)!

Tags: android, junit, media-player

I am using the Android MediaPlayer class and trying to write a testcase which verifies that the onCompletion method is called.
I use it to play the next track after the previous one is finished.

When I run the app using the emulator (2.1 or 4.0) the onCompletion method is called and the next track starts playing, but in the testcase it is not.
Here is the simplified code:

```
public class MediaPlayerControllerTest extends AndroidTestCase implements OnCompletionListener {

    public void testContinuePlayNextTrack() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/5749/01.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        System.out.println("ON COMPLETION!!!!!");
    }
}
```

The code above is normally part of a class MediPlayerController which is used in the app and the test, so it's the same class. I broke the problem down to the few lines of code above.

This cost me a lot of hours. I hope someone has a solution!

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your test case is no longer running when the MediaPlayer finishes playing the mp3. So your solution is to keep the test case alive until the onCompletion() is fired.

I had a similar issue when playing a file from an IntentService. The Service was being destroyed before the callback was initiated.

Comment: How did you solve your problem with the IntentService being destroyed before onCompletionListener was called?

Comment: I overrode onDestroy() to delay until I set a flag indicating my media file finished running. Perhaps not the most elegant solution. The app I wrote was a simple proof-of-concept. In hindsight, I might have built a Service from the ground up instead of using IntentService.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem, and nothing was working for me. From the official Site [(click me)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for the MediaPlayer one can find the following sentence:

> In order to receive the respective callback associated with these listeners, applications are required to create MediaPlayer objects on a thread with its own Looper running (main UI thread by default has a Looper running).

I was a bit lost, as there was no hint for this need on in the API for onCompletionListener himself.

Comment: That explains why it didn't work when playback was started from a background task, but was OK when started from a foreground task.  What a pain...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reason is that the MediaPlayer is a local variable. After the testContinuePlayNextTrack() is finished, the MediaPlayer is collected by GC. So the fix is easy, make your MediaPlayer a member of the class.

```
public class MediaPlayerControllerTest extends AndroidTestCase implements OnCompletionListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    public void testContinuePlayNextTrack() {
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/5749/01.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        System.out.println("ON COMPLETION!!!!!");
    }
```

}